# Any way to integrate SQL Server 2016 with MySql server using linked server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in a MySQL database. And I have the same table in SQL Sever 2016.

When I insert data into SQL Server's table, at the same time, I want to insert that data into the MySQL database's table.

Is there any way to do this task using the SQL Server linked server feature?

Comment: I'm gonna say no.  Maybe you could write a program to do it and run it from a trigger on the SQL server that calls an insert against the MySql db.

Comment: this may help you :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52783/how-do-i-add-a-mysql-linked-server-to-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a forum post [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx) which gives steps to setting up a linked server in SQL Server which points to a MySQL instance:

```
1. Download the MySQL ODBC driver from mysql.com
2. Install MySQL ODBC driver on Server where SQL Server resides
    -Double Click Windows Installer file and follow directions.

3. Create a DSN using the MySQL ODBC driver
Start-> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)
    -Click on the System DSN tab
    -Click Add
    -Select the MySQL ODBC Driver
    -Click Finish
On the Login Tab:
    -Type a descriptive name for your DSN.
    -Type the server name or IP Address into the Server text box.
    -Type the username needed to connect to the MySQL database into the user text box.
    -Type the password needed to connect to the MySQL database into the password text box.
    -Select the database you'd like to start in.
On the Advance Tab:
Under Flags 1:
    -Check Don't Optimize column width.
    -Check Return Matching Rows
    -Check Allow Big Results
    -Check Use Compressed protocol
    -Check BIGINT columns to INT
    -Check Safe
Under Flags 2:
    -Check Don't Prompt Upon Connect
    -Check Ignore # in Table Name
Under Flags 3:
    -Check Return Table Names for SQLDescribeCol
    -Check Disable Transactions
Now Test your DSN by Clicking the Test button


4. Create a Linked Server in SSMS for the MySQL database
SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio -> Expand Server Objects
    -Right Click Linked Servers -> Select New Linked Server
On the General Page:
    -Linked Server: Type the Name for your Linked Server
    -Server Type: Select Other Data Source
    -Provider: Select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
    -Product name: Type MySQLDatabase
    -Data Source: Type the name of the DSN you created
On The Security Page
    -Map a login to the Remote User and provide the Remote Users Password
    -Click Add under Local server login to remote server login mappings:
    -Select a Local Login From the drop down box
    -Type the name of the Remote User
    -Type the password for the Remote User

5. Change the Properties of the Provider MSDASQL
Expand Providers -> Right Click MSDASQL -> Select Properties
    -Enable Nested queries
    -Enable Level zero only (this one's the kicker)
    -Enable Allow inprocess
    -Enable Supports 'Like' operator

6. Change settings in SQL Server Surface Area Configuration for Features
    -Enable OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE support.
7. Change settings in SQL Server Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
    -Enable Local and Remote connections via TCP/IP and named pipes

8. Stop SQL Server and SQL Server Agent
9. Start SQL Server and SQL Server Agent
```

Once you have a working linked server on your SQL Server which points to your MySQL instance, set up a `INSERT` trigger which duplicates any `INSERT` statements on the SQL table to the MySQL table.

Comment: plus 1 for posting entire content,rather than link